# Tensorflow object detection: Continue training

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

Lets say I train a pretrained network like ResNet and set it to detection in the `pipeline.config file` for the `fine_tune_checkpoint_type` attribute. As far as I understand this means that we take the pretrained weights of the model, except for the classification and box prediction heads. Further this means that we can create our own type of labels which will then result as the classification and box prediction heads for the model we want to create/train.

Now, let's say I train this network for 25000 steps and want to continue training later on without the model forgetting anything. Should I change the `fine_tune_checkpoint_type` in the `pipeline.config` to `full` in order to continue the training (and of course load the correct checkpoint file) or should I still let it be set as `detection`?

Edit:

This is based on the information found here [https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/train.proto](http://train.proto):

```
  //   1. "classification": Restores only the classification backbone part of
  //        the feature extractor. This option is typically used when you want
  //        to train a detection model starting from a pre-trained image
  //        classification model, e.g. a ResNet model pre-trained on ImageNet.
  //   2. "detection": Restores the entire feature extractor. The only parts
  //        of the full detection model that are not restored are the box and
  //        class prediction heads. This option is typically used when you want
  //        to use a pre-trained detection model and train on a new dataset or
  //        task which requires different box and class prediction heads.
  //   3. "full": Restores the entire detection model, including the
  //        feature extractor, its classification backbone, and the prediction
  //        heads. This option should only be used when the pre-training and
  //        fine-tuning tasks are the same. Otherwise, the model's parameters
  //        may have incompatible shapes, which will cause errors when
  //        attempting to restore the checkpoint.
```

So, the `classification` only provides the classification backbone part of the feature extractor. This means that the model will start from scratch on many parts of the network.

`detection` restores the whole feature extractor but the "end result" will be forgotten, which means we can add our own classes and start learning these classifications from scratch.

`full` restores everything, even the classes and box prediction weights. However, this is fine as long as we do not add or remove any classes/labels.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have understood that correctly. 
set `fine_tune_checkpoint_type: full` in `piepline.config` to retain all that model has learnt till the last checkpoint.

Comment: This shouldn't be selected as answer since its simply wrong. As of 2020, TF2 models are auto reloaded from previous trained checkpoint from your custom dataset. You dont have to do anything except restarting the training process and the trainer auto detects and loads your own checkpoints. As long as you have an existing checkpoint it will work. Selecting full as an option for fine_tune_checkpoint_type will prevent you from continuing training

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can config the variables to be restored by setting fine_tune_checkpoint_type, the options are detection and classification. By setting it to detection essentially you can restore almost all variables from the checkpoint, and by setting it to classification, only variables from the feature_extractor scope are restored, (all the layers in backbone networks, like VGG, Resnet, MobileNet, they are called feature extractors).

[Click here](https://coderedirect.com/questions/334835/tensorflow-object-detection-api-how-does-the-fine-tuning-of-a-model-works) for more information.